# Google Play Services Plugin - Saved Games

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have been doing research on the Saved Games option in Google Play Games Services Plugin for Unity, and one thing I haven't noticed, is the option to be able to save game data without the interface showing up for the user to choose to save the game data.

Basically I want to be able to save everytime the player finishes a level or unlocks something new. I don't think it would make sense to make a UI pop up everytime that happens. I am also pretty sure that an option like this should exist, as a lot of games on the play store save their game data in the cloud without showing this UI.

Still, no matter how much I look online, I can't seem to find anything on the topic.

Does anyone know how this is done, or an article that would show me how?

P.S. A similar question was previously asked by Jay Kazama about a year ago (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3770593/jay-kazama), but there was never any real answer, so I thought I'd ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [Cubic Pilot](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/samples/CubicPilot/Source/Assets/CubicPilot/GameLogic/GameManager.cs) game uses a `saveToDisk()` to save the game progress:

```
 public void SaveProgress()
    {

        mProgress.SaveToDisk();
        SaveToCloud(null);

    }

    public void AutoSave()
    {
        if (mProgress.Dirty)
        {
            mProgress.SaveToDisk();
            SaveToCloud(mAutoSaveName);
        }
    }
```

I also read a guide about saving in the Unity forums. Here's what I found.

Use the SaveDataBundle

```
public void SaveGame (SaveDataBundle file, Action<bool> callback)
     {
         CommitSaveToCloud(file,"undefined",callback);
     }

Then use the CommitUpdate with the ISavedGameClient object like 

savedGameClient.CommitUpdate ( save, 
                                        updatedMetadata, 
                                        SaveDataBundle.ToByteArray (newBundle), 
                                       (SavedGameRequestStatus status,ISavedGameMetadata game)=>
                                       {
             if(status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success)
             {
                 m_saveBundleMetadata = game;
                 if(saveCreatedCallback != null)
                     saveCreatedCallback(game);
             }
```

You can read more of that in this [Unity thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/894995/how-to-saveload-with-google-play-services.html).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I just implemented it in my code and it worked perfectly!

Comment: which one you used, the Google one or Unity?

Comment: I used the Unity one